# How to automate downloading files?

Tags: download, automation, wget, file-download

I got a book which had a pass to access digital versions of hi-res scans of much of the artwork in the book. Amazing! Unfortunately the presentation of all the these are 177 pages of 8 images each with links to zip files of jpgs. It is extremely tedious to browse, and I would  love to be able to get all the files at once rather than sitting and clicking through each one separately.

archive_bookname/index.1.htm - archive_bookname/index.177.htm each of those pages have 8 links each to the files

linking to files such as `<snip>/downloads/_Q6Q9265.jpg.zip`, `<snip>/downloads/_Q6Q7069.jpg.zip`, `<snip>/downloads/_Q6Q5354.jpg.zip`. that don't quite go in order. I cannot get a directory listing of the parent `/downloads/` folder.

Also, the file is behind a login-wall, so doing a non-browser tool, might be difficult without knowing how to recreate the session info.

I've looked into wget a little but I'm pretty confused and have no idea if it will help me with this. Any advice on how to tackle this? Can wget do this for me automatically?

Answer (score 2):

Using python might be easier. So this is a solution using python. If python is not an option for you, then ignore. :)

***I'm assuming scraping the website is legal.***

Write a simple Python script to loop through `archive_bookname/index.1-177.htm`, scrap them using [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), locate the links with either css class selectors or simple regex matching, then use [`urllib.urlretrieve()`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html) to get the files. That's how I'd do it.

Comment: I definitely have legal access to all the files on it, I know that much. I contacted them to mention that I wished there was an easier way to access the files and never got a response

Comment: why code-format that?!

Comment: Cause I'm much more accustomed to python than wget. Was waiting for someone to post a wget solution. :-)

Comment: @Bibhas sorry, I didn't mean there is anything wrong with your answer, just why did you put "I'm assuming scraping the website is legal" in code formatting?

Comment: @Chris2048 Oh! That's not code tag. That's blockquote. I wanted to highlight that line. Thats why.

Comment: I have to login to access the files. Will that affect this method? (yah ages later.. these solutions were all pretty confusing and I haven't bothered yet)

Comment: Then you have tough luck. If there is no absolute url for these files that you can auto-generate, then it's not possible. If the files are behind some authentication check, this wont work.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify an input html file with

```
wget -F -i <file>
```

so you could just dump the html files and loop through them
(I've added a base url for relative links):

```
for i in <whereYouDumpedFiles>/*.html
do
  wget -F -B <base-url> -i $i
done
```

*alternatively*

you could just dump the links to a file (seperated by newlines) by whatever method and do this:

```
wget -i <url-file>
```

a good way to get at those links would be:

```
lynx -hiddenlinks=ignore -nonumbers -listonly --dump <relevant-url> \
 | sort | uniq | sed /<regexp-pattern-of-urls-you-want>/\!d
```

possibly in a for loop that appends to 'url-file'

Answer (score 0):

Or you can simply use Perl and its brilliant module called www::mechanize. It's really simple to put something together and theres tons of examples on official CPAN documentation.

Comment: 'simply' use PERL is not accurate for me :p I do some programming, but not familiar at all on how to start looking into that..